# OData inheritance missing type information when saving using breezjs

Tags: breeze

I have an Entity Framework model with a base type and a number of subtypes. The model is exposed using WCF as an OData API.

But when I try to create a new child entity I get this error message:

> "Error processing request stream. Type information must be specified for types that take part in inheritance."

When I look at the network traffic I also understands why it fails. It posts to the base entity and there's no information about what child object it is:

```
POST BaseEntities HTTP/1.1
Content-ID: 1
DataServiceVersion: 2.0
Accept: application/atomsvc+xml;q=0.8, application/json;odata=fullmetadata;q=0.7, application/json;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1
Content-Type: application/json
MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0

{"MyID":-1,"CreatedDate":"1999-12-31T23:00:00","CreatedBy":2,"SomeText":"foo","OtherID":11370}
```

Can I somehow add the type information or am I doing something wrong?

Best regards,
Mads